# Dynamic Programming with double recursion

Tags: c++, dynamic

I am new to dynamic programming. I can't understand the double recursion below. Can anyone explain how it works

```
int N; // read-only number of wines in the beginning
int p[N]; // read-only array of wine prices

    int profit(int be, int en) {
      if (be > en)
        return 0;
      // (en-be+1) is the number of unsold wines
      int year = N - (en-be+1) + 1; // as in the description above
       return max(
        profit(be+1, en) + year * p[be],
        profit(be, en-1) + year * p[en]);
    }
```

Comment: Unless `N` is initialized before it's used in the definition of `p`, it won't work at all.

Comment: As for figuring out how the function works, I suggest you trace the calls on paper. Or perhaps use a debugger to step through the code line by line, stepping into the recursive calls.

Comment: `int year = N - (en-be+1) + 1;` can be rewritten simpler `int year = N - (en-be);` (there is no need to add and subtract 1)

Comment: Why is this called "Dynamic programming"? It's just a norma recursive call, to me.   BTW: it must be `constexpr int N = something;` or it cannot compile.

Comment: `profit(be+1, en)` is go into depth until `be > en` as your base condition. After that its pops previous function state of  `profit(be+1, en)` and calls the second recursion `profit(be, en-1)` until `be > en`

Comment: I don't see any dynamic programming here, either. Is the dynamic programming solution one you're expected to write instead of this one?

Comment: About [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming): This piece of code is yet at the stage of 'naive approach' (see Fibonacci example). But we have overlapping sub-problems (`profit(be + 1, en - 1)` will be calculated in both recursions (next to `profit(be, en - 2)` in one and `profit(be + 2, en)` in the other one). So we could make an algorithm based on DP from...

Answer (score 0):

Consider `be` and `en` as the bounds of an integral closed interval `[be; en]`. With each recursion, you remove one element from either bound, until the interval gets empty.

With each new iteration, `en-be` will decrease in value, thus `year` is incremented.

What you actually calculate is (`be0` and `en0` being starting values, i. e. values of first, non-recursive call to the function):

```
    en0
     Σ     ((N-en0) + i) * p[S(i)])
   i = be0
```

Where `S(x)` is some (theoretical) selector function `[be0; en0] -> [be0, en0]` that depends on the maxima calculated during recursion.

This selector function necessarily is bijective (i. e. each p[x] will appear exactly once in the sum for x in [be0; en0]):

```
max
(
    profit(be + 1, en) + year * p[be],
    profit(be, en - 1) + year * p[en]
);
```

With each recursion returning, you'll add the value of an index that has not been in the interval considered during recursion. As S is bijective, it will produce a permutation P of [be0; en0]; however, it cannot produce arbitrary permutations; each sub-interval will *always* be of either of the two forms:

```
[beR, P(beR + 1, ..., enR)]
[P(beR, ..., enR - 1), enR]
```

but never have both `beR` and `enR` somewhere in the middle.

Getting back to the wine image: you sort your wines by whatever defines the order in `p` in a row and with each year, you always remove either the beginning or the end of this row, but never select one in the middle.

So far, there's no [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming) involved, though.

If you look at your recursions closely, you'll discover that you have overlapping sub problems:

```
profit(be, en)
    profit(be + 1, en)
        profit(be + 2, en)
        profit(be + 1, en - 1)    <---
    profit(be, en - 1)
        profit(be + 1, en + 1)    <---
        profit(be, en - 1)
```

i. e. you are doing the same work for one and the same interval more than only once. To introduce dynamic programming, you'd extend your algorithm minimally:

```
int profit(int be, int en)
{
    if (be > en)
       return 0;

    int solution;
    if(getSolution(be, en, solution))
        return solution;

    int year = ...;
    solution = std::max(...); // recursive calls
    addSolution(be, en, solution);
    return solution;
}
```

with appropriate implementations replacing `getSolution` and `addSolution`.